# When i send too many request it gives failed and whole website will stop working

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I am creating a signup page in which user can choose only available username i.e which is not present in the database. so I use ajax for that.. but when I enter too many requests at a time then it gives failed and my website stop working .. after some time all will be fine but for 5-10 min it stop working.

WEBSITE GIVES ERROR:-

This page isn’t working events.collegespike.com didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Code to fetch data from database:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['user_name']) && $_POST['user_name'] != '') {
    $response = array();
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['user_name']);
    $sql = "select username from login_master where username='" . $username . "'";
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
    if ($count > 0) {
        $response['status'] = false;
        $response['msg'] = 'Username already exists.';
    } else if (strlen($username) < 6 || strlen($username) > 15) {
        $response['status'] = false;
        $response['msg'] = 'Username must be 6 to 15 characters';
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z1-9]+$/", $username)) {
        $response['status'] = false;
        $response['msg'] = 'Use alphabet and numeric only.';
    } else {
        $response['status'] = true;
        $response['msg'] = 'Username is available.';
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Ajax code:-

```
//including jquery 2.0.3
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https.://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

//jquery code to fetch data
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#username').keyup(function() {
        var usercheck = $(this).val();
        $('#usercheck').html('<img src="images/loading.gif" width="150" />');
        $.post("signup/check1.php", {
            user_name: usercheck
        }, function(data) {
            if (data.status == true) {
                $('#usercheck')
                   .parent('div')
                   .removeClass('has-error')
                   .addClass('has-success');

            } else {
                $('#usercheck')
                   .parent('div')
                   .removeClass('has-success')
                   .addClass('has-error');
            }
            $('#usercheck').html(data.msg);
        }, 'json');
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML code:-
//code to take input and show output

```
//taking input
<input class="check-form"  name="user_name" id="username" type="text"  placeholder="User Name (please enter unique username)">

//showing output
<span id="usercheck" class="help-block"></span>
<span><i class="ti-check"></i></span>
```

Comment: https://www.easytechguides.com/google-chrome-connection-errors.html can you check this link may be this will help you. I think code is fine no issue in code

Comment: I think your problem is firing too many requests at the same time (due to your `.keyup()` use). I've provided an explanation and solution below.

Comment: Was this helpful @Dhyaneshwar Shukla?

Comment: yes, thanks for helping. I just asked one question can u plz help me

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is coming because of hosting server setting. if you fire too many post request than server will block you for 60 to 120 seconds because of the settings.

**Try using GET request instead of POST request I think it will solve an issue.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#username').keyup(function() {
        var usercheck = $(this).val();
        $('#usercheck').html('<img src="images/loading.gif" width="150" />');
        $.get("signup/check1.php", {
            user_name: usercheck
        }, function(data) {
            if (data.status == true) {
                $('#usercheck')
                   .parent('div')
                   .removeClass('has-error')
                   .addClass('has-success');

            } else {
                $('#usercheck')
                   .parent('div')
                   .removeClass('has-success')
                   .addClass('has-error');
            }
            $('#usercheck').html(data.msg);
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

Comment: this code works fine but I want to know that is this slow down my server speed . or my server load becomes heavy after using this code?

Comment: @DhyaneshwarShukla. No, I don't think it will happen because at a time you don't have many users in register page.also its depend on the server too.

Comment: @DhyaneshwarShukla. if code is working for you so please approve & upvote it so it help full for others too

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is from firing too many requests to the server at the same time.

I notice you are using `.keyup()` and then firing an AJAX request. This means if I was to type the username `Jonathan` it would fire 8 requests all within a second. This will create a bottleneck.

If you open your console, you will notice a single character (a single request) will work fine, type a 2nd character after you have got a response from the first, and it will work again. However typing fast and waiting for all of them to respond will not work. You will see in your console they will be loading and loading until it eventually times out / whatever.

I propose you reduce the requests you're firing off, and only fire a request if the keys have stopped being pressed for x amount of milliseconds.

**Solution:**

Delay the keyup execution. Here's a pure `javascript` solution I've used multiple times that work within my apps. I've simplified it and modified it to hopefully work for your case.

You will notice `delayKeyupExecution()` is called, and we pass `myInput` (in your case this is username), `userNameAjaxCheck` as the callback (this is the function that will contain your ajax request), and `500`, this is the amount of ms to delay it by.

```
// Your username input
var myInput = document.getElementById("username");

function userNameAjaxCheck(params) {
  // Your ajax code to check the username
};

// Delay a function from triggering
function delayKeyupExecution(input, callback, delay) {
  var timer = null;
  var params = null; // Anything you want to pass to the callback function (userNameAjaxCheck)

  input.onkeypress = function() { // Equivalent to your .keyup
    if (timer) window.clearTimeout(timer); 
    timer = window.setTimeout( function() {
      timer = null;
      callback(params); // Pass the params you need
    }, delay );
  };

  input = null;
};

// Execute
delayKeyupExecution(myInput, userNameAjaxCheck, 500);
```